# Setting multiple items on JLabel

Tags: jlabel

I have created a software that is intended to monitor a pharmacy. I'm using NetBeans IDE in Java SE.
My issue is that, I created a database called Payments where all customers payments are recorded there.
I have successfully created a query method that selects all those who are owing me.
Assuming that 3 customers namely A, B, and C are owing me. Yes it would be easier using the JList and JTable. But I wish to use a JLabel to display it as
JLabel.setText("Names of customers owing are customer A, customer B, and customer C"). I need help as to how I can set this multiple list onto a label with a comma.

I'm expecting a simple Java for loop to enable me achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you query method returns a java.util.List of names, you could do something like this:

```
label.setText("<html>Customers owing are: " + String.join(", ", names) + "</html>");
```